# Awk regex for operators

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I want to count and sum number of matches in a file with my awk regex.

The file `file` contains:

```
Gra pes
gra ndma
straw berry
blue Berry
banana
peanut
school
```

I need to make a regex for pattern matching, but I am unsure of how to implement **AND/OR** in regex, despite them having same precedence.

I have tried:

```
awk 'tolower($1) ~ /(gra|straw) (pes|berry)|banana|peanut/ {sum+=1} END {print sum+0}' file
```

So it should be either `(gra pes, gra berry, straw pes, straw berry) OR banana, peanut` and returns 4, since there are 4 matches.

I'm assuming my syntax went wrong with the **OR** banana|peanut, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Any ideas on what went wrong? thank you

Comment: ITYM "or" operators in the subject of your question instead of "for" operators.

Comment: Do you really need a regexp solution? I see in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664504/awk-regex-for-operators#comment1250225_664509) you asked how "to match with `gra peanut` or `peanut gra` - the obvious answer to that in general wouldn't be a single regexp it'd be a condition containing 2 regexps. It's also not obvious that a regexp would be better than a string comparison or hash lookup for the cases in your question. You forced the answer to be a single regexp by asking for that so if that's not really what you need ask a new question about what you want to do, not how

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regexp is fine. Your problem is that you're matching it on `tolower($1)` which is the *first field* (blank separated with the default value of `FS`) converted to lowercase.

So for instance, on the first line (`Gra pes`), it would match the regexp against `gra` and fail.

For the whole record, you want `$0`:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /regexp/ ...'
```

Also note that regexps are not anchored by default so, it will match on `peanutbutter` for instance as `peanut` is found within. If you want the input record to be matched as a whole by the regexp, you'd need:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /^(foo|bar)$/'
```

Which matches on *the beginning of the subject* (`^`) followed by either `foo` or `bar` followed by *the end of the subject* (`$`). Note that the parenthesis are important there. `^foo|bar$` would be either `^foo` (`foo` at the start) or `bar$` (`bar` at the end), so would match on `fooX` or `Ybar` for instance.

Comment: Thank you! What if I'd like it to match with ```gra peanut``` or ```peanut gra``` as well?

Comment: @Hewitt, well then: `/^((gra|straw) (pes|berry)|banana|peanut|gra peanut|peanut gra)$/` or `/^((gra|straw) (pes|berry)|banana|(gra )?peanut|peanut gra)$/`

Answer (score 6):

Just as an alternative to `awk`, you could use `grep`:

```
grep -Eixc '(gra|straw) (pes|berry)|banana|peanut' file
```

- `-E` use extended regex
- `-i` case-insensitive match
- `-x` match whole line only
- `-c` count number of matching lines